# Extremally disconnected rigid infinite Hausdorff compacta(?)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, boolean-algebras

---

***Question***: does there exist an extremally disconnected infinite Hausdorff compact space $\ X\ $ such that the only homeomorphism
$\ h: X\to X\ $ is the identity homeomorphism
$\ h=\mathbb I_X:\ X\to X\quad $**?**

---

Comment: Sir, probably you already possess this knowledge : $I_X$ is the only homeomorphism iff the identity map is the only order isomorphism on the boolean algebra of the clopen subsets of $X$.

Comment: Dear @OnurOktay, it's been more than half a century ago when I was into extremely disconnected spaces and related question, by now I am rusty.

Comment: You might look at this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309122/complete-atomless-boolean-algebras-with-abelian-automorphism-group

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, indeed, very interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This paper, [*Rigid Stone spaces within $\mathsf{ZFC}$*](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1988-0929014-4) by Dow, Gubbi, and Szymański contains relatively easy examples of such spaces.